VSCode on Win 11 shows only part of the context menu. How get old behavior to use all available space?
VSCode on Win 11 shows only part of the context menu in File Explorer

How to use all available space for Context Menu?
I have tried to get the old Windows Context Menu by this register changes but it did not help

Environment
Version: 1.92.2 (user setup)
Commit: fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
Date: 2024-08-14T17:29:30.058Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
